# How to return a 500 error page from a Kubernetes pod application with proxy_intercept_errors enabled in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

My nginx proxy server has `proxy_intercept_errors` enable. I have a common_error setting for 500, 502, 504 etc. My application running on a Kubernetes cluster returns a custom error page for 500. The flow is- nginx-proxy -> some load-balancer -> pod. I want to return the application error page for 500 with keeping `proxy_intercept_errors` enabled. I know by removing 500 from common_error will return error page from the app. But is there any way to overwrite the setting(without removing 500 from nginx & still return app error page) for specific vhost? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks